# Parent $scope in two way binding directive not updating correctly

Tags: angularjs

I was simply trying to add functionality to an existing directive so I can track any changes that occur.  I have a toggle control which is just used to toggle a boolean value.  Here is my directive

```
app.directive('skToggle', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        replace: true,
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            ngModel: '=',
            skcallback: '&callback',
            disabled: '=',
            emit: '@',
            positive: '@',
            negative: '@',
            skTouched:'=?' //THIS IS NEW
        },
        template: '<div class="toggle" ng-class="{ disabled: disabled }" ng-click="disabled || toggle($event)">\
                    <div class="off">\
                        <span>{{neg}}</span>\
                        </div>\
                    <div class="on" ng-class="{ active: ngModel }">\
                        <span>{{pos}}</span>\
                        <div class="control"></div>\
                    </div>\
                  </div>',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            var hasCallback = angular.isDefined(attrs.callback);
            scope.pos = scope.positive || "YES"
            scope.neg = scope.negative || "NO";

            scope.toggle = function (e) {

                if (hasCallback) {
                    scope.skcallback({ event: e });
                } else {
                    ctrl.$setViewValue(!ctrl.$viewValue);
                }

                if (scope.emit === 'true') {
                    $timeout(function () {
                        scope.$emit('toggle');
                    });
                }


            }

            // THIS IS ALSO NEW
            scope.$watch('ngModel', function(newVal, oldVal){
                if(scope.skTouched && oldVal !== undefined && newVal !== oldVal){
                    scope.skTouched.UI.$dirty = true;
                }
            });

        }
    }
});
```

I have commented on which parts of the directive are new.. all I did was add a two-way binding on my directive that takes an object and updates the `UI.$dirty` property on it. The problem is when I print out the object on the screen, the `UI` object never gets updated on the parent `$scope`.  I don't know if I'm just spacing on something easy or if I am doing something wrong but, my directive (child) scope is not updating the parent scope like it should be.

`<div sk-toggle ng-model="feature.enabled" sk-touched="feature"></div>`

Comment: The optional `=?` binding allows you to skip the skTouched attribute when using directive. Thus without html posted it is possible to assume that you didn't provide it when using directive and your check `if(scope.skTouched && ...` prevents updates (since update is impossible)

Comment: no its there and it is updating.. When I inspect the skTouched object inside the directive I can see it update correctly, but same object that skTouch represents doesn't update on the parent

Comment: in jsfiddle it works. So there is no principle error here. How are you tracking the changes in parent? Do you keep in mind that you are not actually changing the object `skTouched`? `parentScope.$watch('skTouch',...` will not trigger since you're doing a 'deep' change

Comment: I use directive two way binding to update the parent scope all the time.. That is the point of it I thought? Can the 2-way binding only work on non-Objects?

Comment: See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Grety/L3cg9w1x/). `$watch` an object doesn't trigger on property change because, in this case $digest cycle just compares references, and there reference really remains the same. Comment format doesn't provide enough space to explanation in detail. You can post another question, i will describe there in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I realized the problem was with using `$dirty` as my variable. Angular must reserve `$dirty` for only use with form controllers, which explains why it wasn't showing up when I printed the entire object out on the page. Simply changing the variable to `dirty` made it work as expected

Comment: you should actually never name your variables starting with a $ simply because angular uses $ for its methods/properties and so you'd avoid situations like this :)

Answer (score 0):

`ngModel` is a core angular directive. It may be that there is a conflict with your using `ngModel` as an attribute to use two-way databinding on.

You may be able to get around this by setting the priority of your directive to be higher than that of `ngModel`.  Add a priority of something > 1 in your directive definition. See the [docs for more info on priority](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile).

Comment: I doubt that's the case, since OP stated clearly that he traced the change in directive. This means `scope.$watch('ngModel', ` worked